# Deny access to folder directly

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, bitnami

I have `bitnami` based instance with `apache` and `php`. I want to secure the phpmyadmin folder, I have read many tutorials on internet , what I did now is that I changed the

`Alias /secret/ "/opt/htdocs/phpmyadmin/`"

and thats how I am accessing the phpymyadmin folder using mydomain.com/secret. but still user can access the folder phpmyadmin , How can I restrict this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you seem to have put the phpmyadmin folder in your web root -- when using an Alias, you'll normally want to put it somewhere *outside* of the `/opt/htdocs/` folder (anywhere, really; if it were me I'd probably just put it in `/opt/phpmyadmin/` but you can put it wherever you want). Update your Alias to point to the correct folder.

Since right now you also have the `phpmyadmin` folder in the web root, when you try to connect to `http://example.com/phpmyadmin` then Apache looks in the web root and finds the matching folder. When you look for `http://example.com/secret`, the alias takes over, but the net result is the same either way.